# Connected app Config

Tags: authentication, mobile, configuration, sdk, user-agent

I would like to know how can I configure my connected app to enter this validation where the user is leaded to 'beginWebViewFlow'. I understand that after SDKv6 if you have not configured this properly the user will be leaded to beginNativeBrowserFlowWithSharedBrowserSessionEnabled (for sdkv11, for lower versions a similar flow).
Followed documentation and used "[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].useWebServerAuthentication = NO" and it didn't change a thing.

Please note that I am using react-native-force to create the project, have tried with SDK10.2.0 and recently tried with SDK 11. Screenshot is for version 11 but i see that I have the similar behavior on 10th version where I should be going to UserAgentFlow instead of browser flow. Thanks in advance

[image]